# Is there a React.js NPM module or any other solution for image/object mutli-selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

Most of the select NPMs are either a dropdown or radio buttons. I am wondering if there is an npm module or a solution for selecting multiple images. The following link provides a perfect example of what I am looking for. 
http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/1907084/Image-Choice-Multiple

I would really appreciate the help :) Thanks react(ers)

I have tried a grid layout papers(material-ui) and inside of each paper I tried to install a checkbox/radio button

Comment: Hi Ahmed, generally speaking SO is for answering specific coding problems.  Not for library recommendationts.  Maybe if you show the code you of what you say you've tried, we can point out how to fix it.

Comment: Yep my bad, I should have put up my code. First time using stackoverflow to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

Wew. Why don't you write your own component for this?

Just simply when image clicked, you set border for it and place a mark icon (use css z-index for icon on top of image).

Comment: We'll try it now.. thank you